# Rails check_box without an object?

Tags: checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I do something like ActionVIew::Helpers::FormHelper#check_box, but without an object to hang it on?

I'm building a user profile editor. Some of my fields are  ordinary booleans, and check_box is great with them:

app/views/users/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :admin %>
<%= check_box :user, :admin %>
```

produces the expected extra hidden field

```
<label for="user_admin">Admin</label>:
<input name="user[admin]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input id="user_admin" name="user[admin]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

and posts the setting as expected.

But my users also have a password, and the behavior I want isn't actually to set or clear a boolean field, but rather to trigger an email-mediated reset protocol. I'd like it to *look* the same as the simple `check_box :user, :admin` case. User objects don't *have* a "reset_password" field, so this is just a syntax error:

```
<%= f.label :reset_password %>
<%= check_box :user, :reset_password %>
```

EDIT: I guess I could make an actual db column / object attribute named `reset_password`, which is always false, but when the controller sees an attempt to set it, it instead launches the reset protocol. But an always-false, read-only attribute seems a tad silly, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's not part of the user profile data, why make it a checkbox?  It could just be a link  instead of a checkbox, either on the user edit screen or on the user profile view.  If you really want it as a checkbox in the form, you could also just make the checkbox part of a subform that would get submitted at the same time as the main form, using a javascript call, and hiding the submit button...

Comment: Thanks for challenging my basic assumptions. I think this action just doesn't belong on the "Settings" screen/form/page. I'll handle it more like I already do "Email": a link on Profile  rather than a checkbox on "Setteings"